# How to set dynamic attribute like (click),(change) from Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to set click attribute from Angular component as i am generating the dynamic html from the component. When i try to Set Attribute (click) it is not working in Angular.

```
var Atag = document.createElement("button");
Atag.setAttribute("(click)","callFunction()");  // This is not working
```

I want result like this

```
<button (click)="callfunction() >Button</button>
```

but some error

[image]

How can i achieve this

Comment: Why not using the Angular click event through component function? Or just use JS `addEventListener()`. Please give more details on the reason behind this approach for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how things work in Angular. The `(click)` attribute is an Angular templating directive that is only available within Angular. During compilation, that attribute is converted to a click event registered to that element, not in the run time.

If you want to achieve that you will have to do it the classical way

```js
var Atag = document.createElement("button");
Atag.addEventLinstener("click", yourCallback);
```

Yet, since you are working with Angular, you should do things the Angular way. Instead of dynamically create an `a` tag, you can create it in your template and hide it behind a flag. For example:

```js
// In your component file
@Component({
// ...
})
export class MyComponent {
    showMyATag = false;

    myFunction() {
        // ....
    }

    someOtherFunction() {
        // When you want to display the a tag, change the flag
        this.showMyATag = true;
    }
}
```

In your HTML template:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="showMyATag">
  <a (click)="myFunction()">Whatever</a>
</ng-container>
```

Do not try to mutate the DOM directly when you are working with Angular. Make your component the source of truth to avoid conflicting changes.